# which method is better to use for a login form doget() or dopost()

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, servlets, authentication

I have come across many websites which either use doget() or dopost() method to handle the username and password fields entered into the login form but as it seems to me when we use doget() we have to ourselves encrypt the username and password fields as they are appended to the URL which is not so in dopost()(work is little less it seems..phewww).

But, I was kinda worried as to whether using dopost() is safe and secure or not as username and password fields are highly sensitive data.

Can anybody please tell me the merits or demerits of using either of the two for use in a login form ?

Comment: IMO you should use doPost(). You must also need to encrypt password while using doPost(). More precisely use SSL.

Comment: @Harry ok thank you for the quick answer but, I am not getting as to why i need to encrypt the encrypt the password even though I am sending it via the request body in dopost...I mean to ask "Is it hackable"??

Comment: I wish there was a system to tell why people down vote without specifying a reason when the question is absolutely genuine >:(

Comment: If you send something unencrypted over the network, you must always assume it's possible for someone to intercept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST has a higher overhead (marginally, if we're honest, but it all adds up), but it doesn't become part of the URL so can't be seen by, say, a casual observer over the user's shoulder - whereas GET can. Both, however, can be equally easily intercepted over the network, so are insecure if you don't use any encryption... GET is just worse, because it can be read by anyone without any deliberate attempt to intercept the password

If you use GET, the user can easily modify the input just by changing the URL, this can be a good or bad thing, you have to decide on a case-by-case basis. Post cannot be as easily modified by the user.

The trick is to encrypt any passwords or sensitive data before you send it. That way there's little to no risk if the packet is intercepted and, since you've encrypted the string, you don't mind if someone reads it over the user's shoulder... you can therefore use GET and save yourself a little bit of overhead at the expense of longer, less pretty URLs. At this stage, neither is really more secure than the other.

In an ideal security world, you'd use POST with SSL so that nothing is in the URL to be very easily intercepted, and nothing that is intercepted can be used easily.

Comment: @John 1 more thing..for using SSL won't I have to buy a SSL certificate from  verisign or someone ???Is there an alternative??

Comment: I did say in an ideal world ;-) encryption is very definitely possible without SSL. In a corporate environment you'd almost always want to use SSL, as it breeds confidence in your company, but java has encryption sufficiently strong built in. Take a look at the Cipher, SealedObject and Key classes, for a starting point (although there are alternatives which may fit better)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should have to use doPost() method because this method don't add your username and password at end of url.
2. If you going to use doGet() method this will append the your username and password end of url.So it is not secure.So i suggest you that go for doPost() method that is more secure.
   And if you want more security you also go SSL(Secure Socket Layer).

Comment: I also thought so when until I saw some big companies using doget instead of dopost. E.x. Facebook and Orkut if you notice they also use doget but the query string is definitely encrypted. So, I wanted to know if there was a reason for that ??